# Google script - Sheets - sort - how to avoid sorting the first row?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

A stupid thing that got me cracking my head. I'm sure you'll laugh, but how do I
sort a sheet without including the first row in the sort?

Here's my code:

```
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test1");
 spreadsheet.sort(4); // or  spreadsheet.sort(4,false); or  spreadsheet.sort(4,true);
```

This sorts by column D, but it also sorts the first row. Column D contains only text.

Funny thing is that if you sort a column which has just numbers/dates, it works and it indeed avoids sorting the first row.

So, how can I sort a column with text and avoid sorting the first row?

I know that I can set a range start at A2 until the last column but this seems "messy". Something like this

```
spreadsheet.getRange('A2:AI').sort({column: 4, ascending: true});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

What about this solution:

Freeze the header row and then perform the sorting operation.

In this way it's easy and readable to select the row that will contain the headers of your spreadsheet and you can apply all the sorting operations with a cleaner syntax:

```js
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test1");
spreadsheet.setFrozenRows(1);
spreadsheet.sort(4);
```

### Reference

[.setFrozenRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setfrozenrowsrows)

Comment: Freezing the row doesn't exclude it from sorting

Comment: It does in my Spreadsheet. Can you post a test spreadsheet with the data you are trying to sort?

Comment: Same for me...freezing the row doesn't exclude it from being sorted

Comment: Freezing the row protects it from sorting in the GUI... interesting that it doesn't work with the script

Comment: Freezing rows won't work if you're calling the `sort(sortSpecObj)` function on a [Range object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) when the frozen rows are included in the range. But it will work if you're using the `sort(columnPosition)` function on a [Sheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) like in Alessandro's example. Both of these sort functions can take a single numerical parameter for the column, so it can be a bit confusing when they get different results. This may be why it didn't work for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find this "messy" too but maybe you could save the first item, sort your column and insert back the first item ?

About the working sort of dates/numbers, maybe the sheet detects that the first cell is the only different one (not a number or a date) and then don't sort it ?